# Ajax.get() vs $(div).load vs html.renderaction MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone clear up some confusion for me.

I need to update a partial view.  When the page first loads, I use @Html.RenderAction to call controller action to update view.  I have a button on the page that when click, will use $(div).load to load HTML directly into a div.

1) If I injected js into the HTML, will it get executed when loaded into the div tag?

2) When should I use ajax.get() instead of $(div).load?  Are there situations when I should use one over the other?

3) Will ajax.get() also execute injected js?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you're adding JS via `<script>` tags then yes it'll render as soon as the page parses and finds the JS.

2) Using `.load()` replaces the content inside a container with the contents of the URL response from the load, whereas `.get()` will just fetch the data, it's up to you to then manipulate the div:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

(Taken from jQuery site), which uses `.html()` which is what `.load()` will be calling underneath. This answers 3) too.